# Cannot edit or update products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, product-import

I imported products in magento 2 backend. All are properly imported

Now when i trying to edit any of those imported products none of them get imported.

I can make changes but save button not working.

I can update imported products by same csv method
And i can also edit or update manually added products.

There is No error on console.

Now i also want manually edit imported products too..

Comment: Inspect the page, see what error is thrown in console. Then solve it

Comment: No error on console all clean

Comment: check error logs.

Comment: When you click the Save button, anything happens? Page reload or loading icon show.

Comment: CDN enable or disable?

Comment: @MohitRane no error logs

Comment: @Jamy button act like disable one nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you can see all the product in backend as well as in list screen means import ran fine. If product save is not working then look in to each tab for a required attribute. You may be missing value for a required attribute which may be hidden in some other tab causing not to allow you to save / update. SO check all the tabs before hitting the save button. Let know otherwise.

Comment: No validation error i checked each and every field of every tab

Answer (score 0):

To support other answer check advanced pricing. Could be a validation error. As within modal it's not immediately obvious what's wrong and why the product isn't saving.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/161459)

Comment: Yes it is - I disagree

Comment: No validation error i checked each and every field.